# Linux script to count and display unique http response codes from a text file

Tags: linux, shell-script

I need to test around 100 urls and send autogenerated email with response code using linux script.
Email content should be  like:

```
                  " 25 http response code 200 \n
                    25 http response code 401 \n
                    25 http response code 503 \n
                    25 http response code 403"
```

I got script to print response codes in a separate file and able to get count with command :

```
awk -F ',' '{print $2}' urlstatus.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

but not able to put in a script and send an email.
can some one help on this please. Any other solution/script also would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already mentioned you got the script to print response code in file urlstatus.txt and As your command response code is present in second column

below associate to counts of occurrence of each response code in file

```
awk -F "," '{a[$1]++}END{for(x in a){print "Response code "x" occurs "a[x]" times"}}' urlstatus.txt >Final.txt
```

Since you have mentioned need to send email use below command

```
mailx -s "subject" "emailid" <Final.txt
```

Comment: Thank you pravee, sending email syntax is correct but the first command is not working as expected.